# Grouping result set from stored procdedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, group-by

I'm having trouble setting up a stored procedure so that the data returned is grouped in a specific way for reporting purposes. I would like to group the result set by Non-Contract Division and for each grouping of Non-Contract Division display the associated data below it from **each** Contract Division.  If a row does not exist for a particular Contract Division I still want to display the Contract Division with a value of 0.

For reference, Non-Contract Divisions include (B,D,E,F,G,H,J,K,L,M,V) and Contract Divisions include (C,O,T,NHQ,National). I was able to achieve the desired grouping by passing in an ID parameter so the result set was for a single Non-Contract Division, but I need to be able to return all Non-Contract divisions at once with the proper grouping.

[The result set should look similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eos2N.jpg)

Some DDL and test data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RcmpDivision]
(
    [ID] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DivisionName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsContractDivision] [bit] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DivisionalTransaction]
(
    [ID] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FiscalYearID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ToDivisionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FromDivisionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsRmCredit] [bit] NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DivisionalTransaction]
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_DivisionalTransaction_RcmpDivision]
FOREIGN KEY([ToDivisionID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[RcmpDivision] ([ID])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DivisionalTransaction] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DivisionalTransaction_RcmpDivision]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DivisionalTransaction]
WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DivisionalTransaction_RcmpDivision1]
FOREIGN KEY([FromDivisionID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[RcmpDivision] ([ID])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DivisionalTransaction] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DivisionalTransaction_RcmpDivision1]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[RcmpDivision]
       ([DivisionName],
       [IsContractDivision])
VALUES
('B',0),('C',1),('D',0),('E',0),('F',0),('G',0),('H',0),('J',0),('K',0),
('L',0),('M',0),('National',1),('NHQ',1),('O',1),('T',1),('V',0)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DivisionalTransaction]
       ([FiscalYearID]
       ,[ToDivisionID]
       ,[FromDivisionID]
       ,[IsRmCredit])
VALUES
(1,7,14,1),(1,4,14,1),(1,9,14,1),(1,7,14,1),(1,4,14,0),(1,7,12,1),(1,9,14,1),(1,3,4,0),
(1,3,4,0),(1,4,14,1),(1,3,1,0),(1,3,12,0),(1,9,2,0),(1,7,2,1),(1,5,15,1),(1,9,16,0),
(1,5,2,1),(1,10,13,1),(1,5,8,0),(1,5,13,1),(1,9,4,0),(1,1,2,1),(1,1,12,1),(1,1,12,1),
(1,1,12,1),(1,1,15,1),(1,1,15,1)
```

Comment: You should get the normal resultset using SQL only and then process the data in your application code to get the desired results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure from your question, but I'm assuming that the `ID` column from your Non-Contract Division records will be tied to the `ToDivisionID` column on the `DivisionalTransaction` table (based off of what I can tell from your seed data).

Based off this assumption, a quick and easy way would be to cross join all of your Non-Contract Divisions with your Contract Divisions, outer join them with `DivisionalTransation`, then using the below sum aggregate function to produce a count:

```
select ncd.DivisionName, cd.DivisionName, 
    sum(case when dt.ID is null then 0 else 1 end) as TotalCount
from dbo.RcmpDivision as ncd
cross join dbo.RcmpDivision as cd
left outer join dbo.DivisionalTransaction as dt
on dt.FromDivisionID = cd.ID
    and dt.ToDivisionID = ncd.ID
where cd.IsContractDivision = 1
    and ncd.IsContractDivision = 0
group by ncd.DivisionName, cd.DivisionName
order by ncd.DivisionName, cd.DivisionName
```

[Here's the result from the given seed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLeXx.png)

Just put this query into your stored procedure, and you should be good to go

Comment: You're assumption about the FK is correct, and the query you provided is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: The DivisionalTransaction table has a FiscalYearID column, and if I modify the query slightly to filter the data by adding **dt.FiscalYearID = 1** to the WHERE clause, the result is missing all of the zero values (ie. where dt.ID is null).  I'm trying to understand why this happens?

Comment: I added _and dt.FiscalYearID = 1_ to the end of the LEFT OUTER JOIN and everything works fine